# why are Files in Applications folder not showing in macOS terminal?

Tags: macos, unix, terminal

[PIC Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdgGd.png) 
I tried this = 
 1. They are not hidden 2. ls -b = no result 3. ls -al = no result.

CHECK OUT THE IMAGE...

Comment: Not sure what your questions, or which files you're referring to.  If you mean .DS_Store and .localized, those are hidden files.  There may be an option to show them in your Finder preferences (I can't turn on my Mac at the moment to verify), but they're operating pretty much as expected.

Comment: Files in the applications folder (not hidden) are not showing in Terminal using ls -a command ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean show hidden files ? you can use this command in your terminal :

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
```

Comment: They are not hidden,  they are App files in applications Folder and they are not showing in Terminal using ls -a / ls -la commands. How Can i see them in terminal ?

Comment: Oh, THOSE files... you ARE seeing them.  All of the .app directories you see are represented in finder by the icon contained in one of the files located in the directory

Comment: How can I  see them in the Terminal in ( macintosh/Applications  ) Path ??  Terminal displays them only in the (macintosh/system/applications ) path & they are not the same apps ?   [ did u check the picture above ]

Answer (score 0):

The confusion, I think, is that if you navigate to /Applications in Finder, it shows you the *combined* content equivalent to:
/bin/ls  /Applications  /System/Applications
If you navigate to /System/Applications in Finder, you will just see:
/bin/ls  /System/Applications
There is no way [that I have found] in Finder to Show *just* the equivalent
of:
/bin/ls  /Applications
It always adds in /System/Applications without ever indicating it has concatenated the two directories.

Comment: Observed under MacOS 12.2.1, Monterey